Mockito - mocking a getter so that it returns null is not working
I have the following code snippet (Java 17, junit 5), and I am trying to get coverage on a test case where the inSellerList is null.
public class MyClass() {
  public myMethod {
    ResDTO resDto = doSomething();
  }

  private ResDTO doSomething() {
    ResDTO resDto = new ResDTO();
    // ...
    List<SellerDTO> editSellerListRes = editSellerList(resDto.getSellerList()); // <---- I need to mock this so that resDto.getSellerList() is null
    resDto.setSellerList(editSellerListRes);
    return resDto;
  }

  private List<SellerDTO> editSellerListRes editSellerList(List<SellerDTO> inSellerList) {
    if (inSellerList == null || inSellerList.size() == 0) {
      System.out.println("I need to have this part covered in the test")
      List<SellerDTO> = new ArrayList<>();
    }
  }
}

In my test scenario, I am using @MockBean to mock resDto.getSellerList so that it returns null, but based on the coverage report, the code inside the if block is not getting covered.
I am limited to only using junit 5 and mockito.
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MyClass.class})
class MyClassTest {
  @Autowired MyClass myClass;

  @MockBean
  private ResDTO resDto;

  @Test
  private void test1() {
  // does not work
  when(resDto.getSellerList()).thenReturn(null)
  // does not work either
  doAnswer(invocation -> {
    resDto.setSellerList(null);
    return null;
  }).when(resDto).setSellerList(anyList());

  myClass.doSomething()
  // assertions
  }
}


In your method doSomething() you create a new instance of ResDTO. Have you thought about putting that into it's own method and making MyClass a Spy so that you can mock the creation of that object? Then you should be able to mock resDto.getSellerList() to be null

This has been asked god knows how many times. How exactly do you expect to the mock to work, when you create new instance in the method, and there is no way to 'give' the configured mock to the unit under test? You either: 1. Refactor the code to make it testable. Or: 2. Use mockitos' MockedConstruction to mock every created instance of a class.

I've skimmed over your code and following are my observation:

You should never write test cases with an intent to falsely increase coverage.
private methods can't be tested and shouldn't be tested. They usually don't contain business logic.
Change visibility of method from private to package protected.
You are confused with @MockBean and @SpyBean.
For more references: Spybean vs Mockbean


How is the difference between a mock and a spy related to the question? The problem is that the code is written in a way that does not allow to supply the unit under with the configured mock.

Increasing the method visibility is not going to help either, OP wants to test doSomething(), not editSellerList().

Since RestDTO isn't a Spring bean at all, that should be @Mock all along. But this isn't the problem, the problem is that the method creates a new instance. The mock field of the test isn't used anywhere at all. I have linked a duplicate showcasing exactly this incorrect assumption.
